# How to prove the relations between the variables in bispherical coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-systems

When I was reading papers about the forces between two charged spherical conductors in a uniform electric field, I was confused with bispherical coordinates the author used to describe the spherical conductors. The schematic diagram is as follows:
[image]

where $β= \ln(\text{PL}_1 / \text{PL}_2) ,  \text{a = OL}_1 = \text{OL}_2$;

[Here is a link about the bispherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bispherical_coordinates).

I want to know why all the points on the sphere (for example sphere 2) satisfy  $β=β2$. What's more, the relations between $\text{xyz}$ and $\text{aβα}$ are not entirely clear to me.Thank you!